# Nexus 3064 strange CPU utilization

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, cpu

My SNMP monitoring showing Nexus 3064 switch CPU utilization `20%`

But on switch cpu history showing 72 Hour maximum CPU%, is this normal?

```
# show proc cpu history

      1   1 11  1  1  11   111 11   11  1 113 1111       11 1 1
    871886278286168068158793166229780186782967001479786891680938
100
 90
 80
 70
 60
 50
 40                                         #
 30                                         #
 20         #          #     #          #  ##             #
 10 ############################################################
    0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....
              0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5

               CPU% per second (last 60 seconds)
                      # = average CPU%



    334571515122345235433355611125223523654335661222362353644463
    678637482746907778793807786736447851192360009523617293532312
100
 90
 80
 70     *                   *                             *
 60    **         *  *     **    *   *  **    **     *  * *   *
 50   *** * *     *  **   ***    *   *  **   ***     *  * *   *
 40 ***** * *   *** **** ****    *  **  *** ****    **  * *****
 30 ***** * *  **************    *  ************ *  ************
 20 ******************************************##*****#**#*#***#*
 10 ############################################################
    0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....
              0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5

               CPU% per minute (last 60 minutes)
              * = maximum CPU%   # = average CPU%



    687777767779768979779898797778977988977777667777886797776777778787777888
    969235992613381786454656352687445460203020996608128502229649807435186873
100                * *    *  *
 90  *         *   * *  **** *   **  ** *               *         *      **
 80  **  **  * *  **** ***** * **** *****       ** *** **    * ** * ** *****
 70 ************************************************************************
 60 ************************************************************************
 50 ************************************************************************
 40 ************************************************************************
 30 ************************************************************************
 20 *#######################################################################
 10 ########################################################################
    0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....6....6....7.
              0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0

                   CPU% per hour (last 72 hours)
                  * = maximum CPU%   # = average CPU%
```

proc table

```
# show processes cpu sort | exclude 0.0


PID    Runtime(ms)  Invoked   uSecs  1Sec    Process
-----  -----------  --------  -----  ------  -----------
12624     61454528  135428515    453   7.00%  t2usd
   27    389745106  316991888   1229   2.00%  ksmd
11310      1311430    553476   2369   1.00%  sensor
11367          113       253    448   1.00%  arp
11371          149       106   1406   1.00%  pktmgr
CPU util  :    4.78% user,    7.97% kernel,   87.23% idle
Please note that only processes from the requested vdc are shown above
```

Comment: Could you specify what software version you are using? We've had the same graphs though no problems in relation to the operation. But when we upgraded to the lastest Major Deployment safe harbor version it all went away..

Comment: @Cown - what does that means `upgraded to the lastest Major Deployment safe harbor version` ?

Comment: It means, that when you go to the Cisco Download center and find the Cisco Nexus 3064 and find the suggested software, which has a yellow star besides it. That means Cisco Suggested the release based on software quality, stability and longevity. At the time of writing Release 7.0(3)I4(7) system software is safe harbor.

Comment: Currently i am running `NXOS image file is: bootflash:///nxos.7.0.3.I4.7.bin`

Comment: Ok, then that's good! That's why i asked.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the legend you'll see that the running average is shown at about 20% (the "#" marks) with the asterisks being peak percentages.  The CLI graph is really imprecise, but what you're generally seeing is periodic (and *very* brief) spikes.

Answer (score 2):

The value being represented by SNMP monitoring is a result of the MIB/OID being used when you are polling the device. A better command to use for correlation would be "show system resources" and look for CPU status.

CPU status: CPU usage percentage in user mode, kernel mode, and idle time in the last one second. For a dual-core Supervisor, CPU is averaged across both cores.

It is most likely using OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.305.1.1.1 which is part of CISCO-SYSTEM-EXT-MIB.